# Let $a, m ∈ Z$ with $m ≥ 2.$ Suppose that $\gcd(a, m) > 1.$ I need to show there does not exist any integer $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod m.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I prove this by using contradiction?

Given the premises, assume that there *does* exists an integer $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod m.$

Then, let $k = \frac{ab - 1}{m},$ where $k \in \mathbb Z$.

So, $$ab = km + 1, b = \frac{km+1}{a} = \frac{km}a + \frac 1a.$$

Then I try to prove $km/a$ is an integer since I know $1/a$ is not.

Comment: Start by assuming the premise and assuming there *does* exist an integer $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod m$.  Then derive a contradiction.

Comment: That's how you prove, after deriving a contradiction, that there doesn't exist an integer $b$ such that ....  Glad I could answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did what you said and got b= (km+1)/a = km/a + 1/a. But I stuck on that because I don't know how to do with km/a.

Comment: Please update you post with your proof in progress.

Comment: I have uploaded it.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation!  I formatted the post to make it "prettier".  Note that the premise informs us that $\gcd(a, m)>1$.

Comment: But I think gcd cannot imply if m is a multiple of a... Sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: Try [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) "Let a and b be integers with greatest common divisor d. Then, there exist integers x and y such that ax + by = d."

Comment: @Alan Your current strategy is too narrow for success, but you’re on the right track.  It’s not reasonable to expect $km/a$ to be an integer, but we *can* show that $km/d$ to be an integer, where $d = \gcd(a,m)$.

Comment: I tried to use Bezout's identity to represent m and a, but it is still a mess...should I focus on the whole function instead of km/a?

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you for your advice. But in my understanding, if we prove km/d is an integer, it still leaves another integer serving from Bezout's identity.

Comment: You can also use the contrapositive. If $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$ for some $b$ then $\gcd(m,a)=1$.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ if $\,d\mid a,m\,$ then $\,d\mid ab\!-\!km = 1.\ $ $\phantom{}$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) for the general result. More generally if $\,\gcd(a,m)>1\,$ then $\,a\,$ is a zero-divisor so [not a unit (invertible)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168064/242)

Comment: @DDD No, I’m saying do exactly as your current proof but instead of looking at $(km+1)/a$, look at $(km+1)/d$, which is a multiple of $b$ and hence also an integer.